# How to install packages using commands such as npm gulp git

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, xampp, uikit, installation

This might be a silly question for those who know but to be honest, I have no idea how to even ask this question. I will try my best:

I am working on building a site using uikit which I am very familiar with and its almost like a copy of bootstrap. I am not familiar with Uikit Customizer implementation which is what I am stuck with. The support people suggested I should follow the commands in the link below to get uikit [customiser](http://getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html) to work 
- https://github.com/uikit/uikit#developers

Some of the commands are:

```
npm install --global gulp
git clone git://github.com/uikit/uikit.git
```

My questions are -
1) Where to enter these commands? The documentation just shows the commands
2) If it is in command prompt, then how do I know it gets installed correctly for my current htdocs site ? What is the scope of the install?
3) I am building an html template that others can use and not have to do all these installs. After I install using above commands, will my package work for everyone who downloads my site files to their site's root? 
4) Instead of installing these, can I copy some files to the appropriate folders in my site?

I have asked uikit through githuib and they just direct me to the link above.
Again - I am really confused so please feel free to edit the question if someone can reword it better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Javascripts can be run usually on the browser only. Node js allows you to run js on the server side.

Process:

1. 1) Goto Node.js and downoad it. Its a file that you can double click
   and will take you through windows setup
2. 2) Create a folder called npm in your C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm
3. 3) Open command prompt (Start button on windows and type cmd)
4. 4) C:\Users\  - This will show up on your command prompt
   by default
5. 5) To install gulp - type "npm install gulp"  - So your cmd window
   will look like this C:\Users\username> npm install gulp

This is how you enter commands.

Also to enter github commands - such as git://github.com/uikit/uikit.git

1) Install bower - npm install bower - Same way as above

2) Commands are here - http://bower.io/ - bower install git://github.com/user/package.git

Answer (score 0):

Want you to change UIkit repo?

UIkit is a framework to build FrontEnd, and if you want to change something of the source code (for custom) you want to install nodejs and gulpjs to rebuild your changes, and then deploy the rebuild changes (css, js, fonts).

Best Regards!.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have built many themes using uikit and bootstrap and sold them so I am aware of what uikit is. My question was - If I wanted to mimick their customizer (link provided in my question), they are telling me to run those commands. Can you please specifically answer my questions? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already done this work for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/uikit

To install this all you have to do is,

```
npm i -S uikit
```